# Ordering List Within a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there an easy way to sort a list within a list so that the values go from least to greatest or vice versa? I can so far only find information on ordering the lists themselves based off the leading value.

Here is an example:

```
data = [[8,7], [10,5,], [8,10]]

>> [[7,8], [5,10], [8,10]
```

Comment: FYI: Those are `list()`s, which use square brackets, not `tuple()`s, which use round brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is a list of lists, no tuples involved here, You can also do it with a combination of built-in methods [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> data = [[8,7], [10,5,], [8,10]]
>>> 
>>> list(map(sorted, data))
[[7, 8], [5, 10], [8, 10]]
```

In Python3, `map` returns an iterator, so if you need it as a list, you need to convert it back with `list`, otherwise, if you are using it in a loop then no need to convert it to a list. It saves memory this way.

Edit:

Replying to your comment, you can do something like:

```
>>> def f(lst):
        lst = sorted(lst)
        return(lst[0], lst)

>>> print(*map(f, data))
(7, [7, 8]) (5, [5, 10]) (8, [8, 10])
```

Or more compact but less readable:

```
>>> print(*map(lambda lst: '{} - {}'.format(lst[0], lst), map(sorted, data)), sep='\n')
7 - [7, 8]
5 - [5, 10]
8 - [8, 10]
```

Comment: Is there a function I can use to print the leading variable befor the number pair?  ie.   [7,8] as 7, [7,8]. The function I tried using prints it as list of sorted pairs then leading variables.

Comment: Glad to be helpful to you, consider accepting the one you think helped you in your issue.

Answer (score 10):

Use a list comprehension to sort each element (each `list` object) in `data`:

```
data = [sorted(x) for x in data]
```

`data` is now:

```
[[7, 8], [5, 10], [8, 10]]
```

You could also do this:

```
map(sorted, data)
```

Then use `list` on that `map` object to actually turn it into a list...

Answer (score 1):

it depend if you want to order them in-place or you want a new copy with the list orderer

for the new copy, the other answer already show you how, for instance

```
data = [[8,7], [10,5], [8,10]]
new = [ sorted(elem) for elem in data ]
print(new)
```

for ordering them in-place use a for-loop and call `.sort` on them

```
data = [[8,7], [10,5], [8,10]]
for elem in data:
    elem.sort()
print(data)
```